# Is there anyway to avoid locks in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to migrate some data from one collection to other collection in the same database in mongodb. I have around 50K records. While inserting the mongodb get locked and it is affecting the application. Is there a way to handle the locking system in the mongodb ?

Thanks,
Prats

Comment: Please add which version of mongoDB you use!

Comment: There is literally a 90% chance it is not the locks but instead your computers bottleneck in the form of IO limitations or something similar, can you give us a mongodb version and iostat -x for the time it gets locked? Can you also describe your computer a little and your dataset size?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0

Comment: please post the server version when you start MongoDB, the shell version cna be different to the server version

Comment: It is the same version

Comment: I think this may be a physical resource limitation on your server, basically you are bogged down in migration and your computers IO is doing overtime, you could try as @ppeterka mentions and break the migration into batches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this article: [Goodbye global lock – MongoDB 2.0 vs 2.2](http://blog.serverdensity.com/goodbye-global-lock-mongodb-2-0-vs-2-2/) the global locking [that was known to affect](http://ethangunderson.com/blog/two-reasons-to-not-use-mongodb/) mongoDB  is supposedly gone when using version >=2.2.

If you have an old instance, and upgrade is out of scope, I'd try breaking up the migration into smaller batches (max 100 documents at a time, if they are small enough), and waiting small amounts of time (50ms or so) between each batch runs. This is an ugly and slow workaround, but might allow you to continue, while being onnline at the time...

**EDIT**
Hmmm, strange, your version should be free from the global write lock situation. I'd probably try the smaller batches approach...

**EDIT2**
And Sammaye is right: this might be the good old IO bottleneck issue too... try to see how well your disks fare in this aspect to be sure.